# Error when using multiple data frames in ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am trying to create a barplot with one df, and then use another to define line segments for errorbars.

The data df looks like this:

```
> avgN1_df
  whichERP condition     n1amp     n1sem
1     last      cong -7.411417 0.7729889
2     last    incong -8.659391 0.7412792
3     last     irrel -5.494083 0.6169797
4    other      cong -5.620657 0.6939584
5    other    incong -6.859358 0.6537592
6    other     irrel -4.761974 0.5662695
```

and the first set of line segments for the errorbars is set up as the following:

```
> dfl1
  xstops ystops
1  0.875  -10.8
2  0.875  -11.0
3  1.125  -11.0
4  1.125  -10.8
```

Negative is plotted upwards for these plots, so I'm trying to get errorbars that appear above the data. The following is what I've tried:

```
tplot = ggplot(data=avgN1_df, aes(x=condition, group=whichERP, y=n1amp)) +
# means
geom_bar(aes(fill=condition, alpha=whichERP),stat='identity',position=pd, width=0.5) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=n1amp-n1sem, ymax=n1amp+n1sem), size=1, width=0.1, position=position_dodge(0.5)) +

# significance indicators
geom_line(data=dfl1, aes(x=xstops,y=ystops))

windows()
print(tplot)
```

R is throwing an error saying 'object 'whichERP' not found' -- it seems like trying to use geom_line with the second data frame is for some reason causing it to forget properties of the main df. I am vexed. If the problem pops out to anyone, any help would be much appreciated!

-
Justin

Comment: You put the `group` aesthetic in the global `ggplot` call, so every layer will try to group the data by that variable.  You are getting an error because that variable is not in your second dataset so `geom_line` fails.  You could move `group` into the layer it pertains to or tell `geom_line` not to inherit global aesthetics via `inherit.aes = FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks aosmith, that was exactly my problem. Cheers!